# Network Is Unreachable When Installing Jenkins On Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking, jenkins

So I want to install jenkins on my ubuntu 20.04 VPS and always got the error "Network is unreachable". I tried to install it with wget like this :

```
wget https://get.jenkins.io/war-stable/2.332.3/jenkins.war
```

And always got error :

```
Resolving get.jenkins.io (get.jenkins.io)... 52.167.253.43
Connecting to get.jenkins.io (get.jenkins.io)|52.167.253.43|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/jenkins/war-stable/2.332.3/jenkins.war [following]
--2022-10-18 01:47:10--  https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/jenkins/war-stable/2.332.3/jenkins.war
Resolving mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn (mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn)... 101.6.15.130, 2402:f000:1:400::2
Connecting to mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn (mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn)|101.6.15.130|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn (mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn)|2402:f000:1:400::2|:443... failed: Network is unreachable.
```

I already install ca certificate and use java 11.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: What is the result of : `echo quit | openssl s_client -host eff.org -port 443`

Comment: The result is quite long @GillesQuenot, it shows SSL certificate and SSL-Session

Comment: If you have a VPN, try to use it with another IP. For a reason or another, maybe you are banned from your IP